# MATLAB plot all lines except which contain value -1

Tags: matlab, plot

How can i plot all the lines except line who has value "-1"

I have arrays like

```
theArray=
1 12
2 15
3 -1
4 154
5 -1
6 0
7 0
8 -1

plot(theArray(:,1),theArray(:,2)
```

is there a way to plot theArray without the 3 5 8 lines?

Comment: `plot(theArray(~any(theArray<0,2),1),theArray(~any(theArray<0,2),2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can set any -1 values to `NaN` so `plot` can skip plotting the points.  As such, you can do something like this:

```
theArray(theArray(:,2) == -1,2) = NaN;
plot(theArray(:,1), theArray(:,2));
```

The difference between this approach and Andrey's approach is that no lines will be plotted at any `y` co-ordinates that are set to `NaN`.  If you need the lines drawn in between those points, then Andrey's approach is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter those lines first :

```
badIndexes = theArray(:,2) == -1;
theArray(badIndexes,:) = [];
```

and then plot:

```
plot(theArray(:,1),theArray(:,2)
```